# user verification value - where to store

Tags: database-design, rdbms

Quick question as relates to database.

Where would you store the value of "UserVerified"? (The one that occurs after the user has checked his email and clicked on the "Verify" link with the hash value at the end).

Would you store it in the User table? (Along with username, hash) ?

Or in the UserProfile table (along with first name, last name, email, phone, etc) ?

Please note that both tables will always contain 1 entry for a user, such that when a user is created, automatically a userprofile is created as well.

Comment: If there's always a 1-1 correspondence between the tables why do you need both? It would simplify decisions like this if you just had 1 table, and I see no advantage to having 2.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the two tables, it sounds like `User` contains metadata about the user, such as the `hash` field (and probably other things the user never enters, but are still important to keep track of in the system). So if you consider `isVerified` to also be metadata, then it should probably go in the `User` table with the related fields.